# Formatting currency to locale specific formats

Tags: java, concurrency, formatting, currency-formatting

I want to be able to format the double price to a locale specific format.
You can achieve this by using the code below:

```
NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale).format(20.0);
```

However only 21 locales are supported and I need to support more than those countries. It will be nice to be able to format the price given the ISO country code.
For example given the ISO country code *CAN* I want to format price to *$20.00*, etc.

Does java has support for this? If not is there a open source version (such as joda time for Date) that can achieve this?

Comment: Java supports more than 200 locales, but it only has some of them as constants. More info in [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) class definition. What have you tried?

Comment: How do you get the locale instance for the once with no constants defined?

Comment: `Locale locale = new Locale(language_code, country_code);`

Comment: What is the locale_code? Is it ISO country code?

Comment: Sorry if can't be seen, but I've post a link in my first answer in the  "Locale" word. And it is language code first, then country code.

Comment: I see it is the ISO country code and language code you need to pass into the constructor. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a `Locale` based on the language and country you need. By default, Java has some of these locales as constants, but it supports more than 200 countries:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("es", "pe"); //Spanish, Peru
```

More info:

- [`java.util.Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html)

Comment: For future readers, there is a bug specifically for Peruvian currency in previous versions of Java: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7028073

Comment: Notice that starting tomorrow, `S/` will be the new correct symbol. Source: http://busquedas.elperuano.com.pe/normaslegales/ley-que-cambia-el-nombre-de-la-unidad-monetaria-de-nuevo-sol-ley-n-30381-1322623-1/

Comment: @gian1200 thanks! After reading the new law in the official newspaper of Peru, seems that the old bug won't be a bug anymore and it will need to be (rollbacked) fixed again.

Answer (score 0):

```
NumberFormat f = NumberFormat.getInstance(loc);
if (f instanceof DecimalFormat) {
    ((DecimalFormat) f).setDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown(true);
}
```

have you tried DecimalFormat it has many methods to customize the output please check the various setMethods here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#method.summary